# How to find Mean and Standard Deviation from 2 data points

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

The question reads "**Suppose that the BMIs of American women of ages 50 to 59 also follow a normal distribution approximately but with different mean and standard deviation. It has been found that 5.05% American women of ages 50 to 59 have BMIs less than or equal to 20.4 kg/m^2 and 10% have BMIs greater than or equal to 38.9% kg/m^2. What are the mean and standard deviation of the BMI distribution for American women of ages 50 to 59?"** I found that
x-mu/sigma = z
So I plugged my numbers in and got two equations 20.4 - mu/sigma = -1.64 and 38.9 - mu/sigma = 1.28. My question is how do I go from here to solving mu and sigma?

Comment: Hint: you have two equations, and two unknown variables.

Answer (score 1):

Using your data you have that

$$\begin{cases}
\mathbb{P}[X<20.4]=5.05\%\\
\mathbb{P}[X>38.9]=10\%
\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases}
\mathbb{P}[X<20.4]=5.05\%\\
\mathbb{P}[X<38.9]=90\%
\end{cases}$$

Now using Z-tables you can find the two quantiles

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{20.4-\mu}{\sigma}=-1.640\\
\frac{38.9-\mu}{\sigma}=1.282
\end{cases}$$

Solving the system in $\mu;\sigma$ you get the solution